# Usage of である in this sentence

Tags: translation, meaning, usage

In this sentence:

> 当時の人間どもの手**である**改造を施された

I'm not sure if である is being used as the copula or the で part is used to mean "by the hands of this people" as in means of action

Comment: Parse it 手で、ある改造を・・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
で  : by
ある: one(or some)
```

ある is just modifying 改造, like "ある日(one day)". If splitting the sentence by a space, it becomes:

```
当時の　人間どもの　手で　ある改造を　施された
```

or changing its order:

```
ある改造を当時の人間どもの手で施された
```